# how to debug a c# binary file

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm trying to debug a exe file which is a .net c# file. I don't have the code for this file so I'm using Immunity Debugger. However is hard to make sense of the code because all I can see is calls like:

```
CALL clr.AABBCCDD
```

Is there any other debugger most appropriate to debug c# code? The code is obfuscated (yes, it is a malicious file) with some custom obfuscator. UnConfuser, ILSpy, de4dot, .net reflector and alike were useless. Anyway all I want is to follow binary code and eventually manually patch it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear on your situation. Are you saying that you cannot decompile the .NET IL, or that when you do it gives you obfuscated C#? What would another debugger/decompiler give you that you don't already have?

Comment: Yes. Since I don't have access to the source code because it is obfuscated I tried to debug it. As I say, Immunity is not very helpful. So my question is... what is the best debugger to step over binary code generated by .net c#.

Comment: It heavily depends on how the obfuscation was performed and what kind of information is left. In the worst case, you only get a fully native app, and won't be able to see MSIL at all and then no managed debugging experience can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of low level debugging, .NET support and missing source code suggests using [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg), [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) and [sosex](/questions/tagged/sosex) together. If you need to automate repetitious tasks, add [pykd](/questions/tagged/pykd).

Benefits are:

- x64 support (which not all debuggers have)
- Microsoft toolchain, which has most official .NET support
- have the original behavior as given by .NET, not a recompiled modified version of the binary

Disadvantages that will remain:

- no IL code stepping. You'll still step in native x86 code (JIT-compiled)

Potential other disadvantages:

- hard to get into it. Cryptic commands.